# WordPress Multisite SSL htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, multisite

I would like to redirect from non-https to https on my site and subdomains, but I'm having issues to solve it.

This is my setup:

```
www.domain.de
www.sub.domain.de
www.sub2.domain.de
www.sub3.domain.de
```

I can open all links by https and it works, but due duplicate content I would like to use https only.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this is my htaccess so far... but it redirects the subdomains to the primary domain :(

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: this redirects the subdomains to the primary domain, how could I fix that? thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing changes with the domains. If you have a problem, it is only for you, clear your cache or try with another browser.

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, [you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pluging: https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/
It is a simpel way to do it, it redirect everything from HTTP to HTTPS.